# ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW does not work when messagebox is assigned to a variable

Tags: python, multithreading, ctypes

[edit] so I have a multi-threading python program that has one thread to create a message box and another to close it down. I couldn't understand why this works:

```
import ctypes
import threading
import time

def worker(title,close_until_seconds):
    time.sleep(close_until_seconds)
    wd = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW(0, title)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(wd,0x0010,0,0)
    return

def MessageBoxW(text, title):
    global loopMessageBox
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, 0)          
t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=('TEST_CLOSE', 3))
t.start()
MessageBoxW('112','TEST_CLOSE')
```

But this doesn't

```
import ctypes
import threading
import time
loopMessageBox = None

def worker(title,close_until_seconds):
    time.sleep(close_until_seconds)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(loopMessageBox,0x0010,0,0)
    return

def MessageBoxW(text, title):
    global loopMessageBox
    loopMessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, 0)
    if loopMessageBox == 1:
          MessageBoxW('112','TEST_CLOSE')
t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=('TEST_CLOSE', 3))
t.start()
MessageBoxW('112','TEST_CLOSE')
```

Tkinter isn't a solution as I already have it running on the main thread. Also the reason I want to assign variable to MessageBoxW is because I want to create a loop when user click on okay button. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: @MarkTolonen I've updated the post, thanks!

Comment: You removed the `FindWindow` used in the first code so the `WM_CLOSE` (0x0010) isn't being sent to the right window anymore.  I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish in the second code.  Recursively calling MessageBoxW isn't a good way to loop, either.  Explain what you expect the second code to do when it works.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I would like a dialog to be created from a thread. It should always stay on top of all windows and cannot be closed by user (hence the recursive function). 

Then on another thread I want it to watch cpu usage of a certain program and when this cpu usage is less than, say 5 for say, 10 seconds then close down that dialog

I know I've removed the `FindWindow` function but that window has been assign to loopMessageBox then shouldn't `WM_CLOSE` be sent to the correct one?

Comment: You're not assigning the window handle to `loopMessageBox`.  You're assigning the result of the dialog box (which button you clicked).  And don't use recursion to loop.  Use a while loop.  Every time it recurses the stack increases...do that enough (granted, quite a lot) and the stack will fault.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks for your reply. I tried while loop but it didn't work. Anyway I will settle for this dialog box to be non-recursive so all good